# How can I register for `IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback` from C#

Tags: c#, windows, com, print-spooler-api

I am trying to receive a callback from a v3 printer driver or port monitor, but want to do so from C#.  [The docs say that we should be able to just pass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162919(v=vs.85).aspx) an object implementing `IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback` to `RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications`, and there is a sample in C++, but I cannot find a TLB to be able to implement this interface in C#.

Further, `RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications` doesn't appear to be exported from the dll named in the documentation (`Spoolss.dll`).

How can I implement `IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback` without a TLB?  How do I locate `RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, consider writing a v4 print driver instead.  While it is not likely that v3 driver support will be dropped at any point soon, v4 drivers are certainly the way to go for new development.  They also have a .Net API for callbacks, which avoids having to write the interop yourself.  [See `PrinterExtensionSample`.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/v4PrintDriverSamples/PrinterExtensionSample)

## Implementing a COM interface without a TLB

To implement `IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback` and the `IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel` and the `IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject` interfaces it refereces, we can find their definitions in `prnasnot.h`, reproduced below.

```
// ... snip ...
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel,        0x4a5031b1, 0x1f3f, 0x4db0, 0xa4, 0x62, 0x45, 0x30, 0xed, 0x8b, 0x04, 0x51);
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback,       0x7def34c1, 0x9d92, 0x4c99, 0xb3, 0xb3, 0xdb, 0x94, 0xa9, 0xd4, 0x19, 0x1b);
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject,     0x77cf513e, 0x5d49, 0x4789, 0x9f, 0x30, 0xd0, 0x82, 0x2b, 0x33, 0x5c, 0x0d);
// ... snip ...
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject, IUnknown)
{
    // ... snip ...
};
// ... snip ...
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel, IUnknown)
{
    // ... snip ...
};
// ... snip ...
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback, IUnknown)
{
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(
        THIS_
        _In_        REFIID riid,
        _Outptr_ void   **ppvObj
        ) PURE;

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)(
        THIS
        ) PURE;

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)(
        THIS
        ) PURE;

    STDMETHOD(OnEventNotify)(
         THIS_
         _In_ IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel    *pChannel,
         _In_ IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject *pData
         ) PURE;

    STDMETHOD(ChannelClosed)(
         THIS_
         _In_ IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel    *pChannel,
         _In_ IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject *pData
         ) PURE;
};
```

The `IID`s at the top and the method ordering and signatures allow us to [translate these to the appropriate `ComImport`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkcominteroptutorialdeclaringanunmanagedcominterface).

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("77cf513e-5d49-4789-9f30-d0822b335c0d")]
public interface IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject
{
    void AcquireData(out IntPtr data, out uint cbData, out IntPtr schema);
    void ReleaseData();
}

[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("4a5031b1-1f3f-4db0-a462-4530ed8b0451")]
public interface IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel
{
    void SendNotification(IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject data);
    void CloseChannel(IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject data);
}

[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("7def34c1-9d92-4c99-b3b3-db94a9d4191b")]
public interface IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback
{
    void OnEventNotify(IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel channel, IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject data);
    void ChannelClosed(IPrintAsyncNotifyChannel channel, IPrintAsyncNotifyDataObject data);
}

public enum PrintAsyncNotifyUserFilter : uint
{
    kPerUser = 0,
    kAllUsers = 1
}

public enum PrintAsyncNotifyConversationStyle : uint
{
    kBiDirectional = 0,
    kUniDirectional = 1
}
```

## Finding RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications

Since the C++ sample works as-is, and `RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications` is an import – rather than a macro – the linker will look at the `WinSpool.lib` file named in the documentation to find the appropriate dll.  We can do the same using `dumpbin`.

```
c:\Drop>dumpbin -headers "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64\WinSpool.Lib" > out.txt
// ... snip ...
  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 8664 (x64)
  TimeDateStamp: 56F9F510 Mon Mar 28 22:22:56 2016
  SizeOfData   : 00000030
  DLL name     : WINSPOOL.DRV
  Symbol name  : RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications
  Type         : code
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 162
  Name         : RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications
// ... snip ...
```

which shows that `RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications` is actually exported from `WINSPOOL.DRV`.

```
[DllImport("WINSPOOL.DRV", PreserveSig = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string name,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid notificationType, PrintAsyncNotifyUserFilter filter,
    PrintAsyncNotifyConversationStyle converstationStyle,
    IPrintAsyncNotifyCallback callback, out PrintAsyncNotificationSafeHandle handle);

[DllImport("WINSPOOL.DRV", PreserveSig = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int UnRegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications(IntPtr handle);

public sealed class PrintAsyncNotificationSafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    public PrintAsyncNotificationSafeHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return UnRegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications(handle) == 0 /* S_OK */;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add CharSet = CharSet.Auto to the RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications preamble.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS, what error message were you getting?  `dumpbin` is pretty clear on the exported name and all strings are explicitly marked with `MarshalAsAttribute`.  What framework, OS SKU, bitness, and version are you running?

Comment: Sorry false alarm - I just removed CharSet and rebuilt and the OnEventNotify was called just fine. Thank you for posting this - it's been so useful!

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS, I'm glad to hear it.  Thanks,